# Stripe Payment In expo React Native App Using Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo, stripe-payments

I have been searching a lot but non of them fits in my requirements.
Just i need to know what is the difference between all the library of integrating stripe in expo react native app, for exemple, i found : @stripe/stripe-react-native , tipsi-stripe , expo-stripe-checkout ...

Answer (score 2):

**stripe-react-native:**

You can integrate stripe-react-native [0] into a ReactNative app, referencing the guide here (and the installation steps on the github repo linked in [0]): https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native

**tipsi-stripe:**

tipsi-stripe was a community built and maintained library to use Stripe in a ReactNative app but that is no longer updated or maintained, so would recommend just using stripe-react-native.

**Expo:**

stripe-react-native is also supported in an Expo app, you would get started with https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native#expo and https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/.

Since you're using Expo, this is the route I would recommend you take.

[0] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native